# Bind Cascade function to an element not yet in DOM

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I bind the cascade function to an element not yet in the DOM:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
        var defaults = {};
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

     // REST OF THE CODE NOT IMPORTANT FOR THE QUESTION //

    };
})(jQuery);
```

The Partialview that will be loaded will have:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PTDistrict_Id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PTDistrict_Id, Model.PTDistrictList, HeelpResources.PTDistrictViewDropDownListFirstRecord, new { id = "districtDropdown" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PTDistrict_Id)
```

I have tried this but no luck:

```
$(document).on("change", "#districtDropdown", function () {
    $.cascade({
        url: "/Address/ListCouncilByDistrict",
        paramName: "districtId",
        firstOption: 'Selecione o Concelho...',
        childSelect: $("#councilDropdown")
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't. You'll have to either bind it after an event such as click, or bind it after the ajax request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Like that

```
$(document).on("change", "#districtDropdown", function () {
    $(this).cascade({
      ...
    });
});
```

Comment: At least be so kind giving explanation when down voting whoever you are because it looks like some as*hole is hitting just like that

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it. Period...

But you may use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler. As it's description says:

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the **future**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for your situation:

```
<select>
    <option class="event" data-action="Cascade" data-someParameter="fooBar">Foo</option>
</select>  
    <script>

    var Event = {
      Cascade: function(ele){
      //enter your actual cascade function.
         alert(ele.attr("data-someParameter")); //alerts "123"
      };
    };

    $(".event").on("click",function(){
       var ele = $(this);
       Event[ele.attr("data-action")](ele);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. And how can I adapt your code for razor: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PTCouncil_Id, Model.PTCouncilList, new { id = "councilDropdown" }) ?